# How to split a URL string with parameters into an array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to break up a string like this one:

fname=bill&mname=&lname=jones&addr1=This%20House&...

I want to end up with an array indexed like this

```
myarray[0][0] = fname
myarray[0][1] = bill
myarray[1][0] = mname
myarray[1][1] = 
myarray[2][0] = lname
myarray[2][1] = jones
myarray[3][0] = addr
myarray[3][1] = This House
```

The url is quite a bit longer than the example. This is what I've tried:

```
var
    fArray = [],
    nv = [],
    myarray = [];

fArray = fields.split('&');

// split it into fArray[i]['name']="value"
for (i=0; i < fArray.length; i++) {
    nv = fArray[i].split('=');
    myarray.push(nv[0],nv[1]);
    nv.length = 0;
}
```

The final product is intended to be in 'myarray' and it is, except that I'm getting a one dimensional array instead of a 2 dimensional one.

The next process is intended to search for (for example) 'lname' and returning the index of it, so that if it returned '3' I can then access the actual last name with myarray[3][1].

Does this make sense or am I over complicating things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line `myarray.push(nv[0],nv[1]);` pushes two elements to the array `myarray`, not a single cell with two elements as you expect (ref: [array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)). What you want is `myarray.push( [nv[0],nv[1]] )` (note the brackets), or `myarray.push(nv.slice(0, 2))` (ref: [array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)).

To simplify your code, may I suggest using [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var q = "foo=bar&baz=quux&lorem=ipsum"; 
         // PS. If you're parsing from a-tag nodes, they have a property 
         // node.search which contains the query string, but note that 
         // it has a leading ? so you want node.search.substr(1)

var vars = q.split("&").map(function (kv) {
               return kv.split("=", 2);
           });
```

For searching, I would suggest using [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var srchkey = "foo";
var matches = vars.filter(function (v) { return v[0] === srchkey; });
```

NB. array.filter will always return an array. If you always want just a single value, you could use [array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or a bespoke searching algorithm.

Comment: @PeterSnow, amended my answer with the searching part, which I managed to miss on the first round.

Comment: thanks nikc.org, I made a function to do that, but your's is better! However, I was hoping to extract the index of the fields I require to variables, so that I can refer to an element with 'out[lname][1]' instead of 'out[2][1]'. That was to make it tolerant of changes in the url string. Unfortunately though I can't find a way to assign the key of 'lname' (etc) to a variable, so it looks like it's back to the drawing board. Thanks though, I learnt about a few new javascript functions!

Comment: @PeterSnow The array.filter method does receive the index as a param as well, I just chose not to use it in the example. As stated in the docs (which I link to in my answer): *"callback is invoked with three arguments: the value of the element, the index of the element, and the Array object being traversed."*.

If you return the value for `index` in the `filter`/`some` callback, that's what you'll have.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < fArray.length; i++) {
    nv = fArray[i].split('=');
    myarray.push([nv[0],nv[1]]);
}
```

`nv.length = 0;` is not required, since you're setting `nv` in each iteration of the `for` loop.

Also, use `var i` in the `for`-loop, otherwise, you're using / assigning a global variable `i`, that's asking for interference.

Comment: Appreciate that. I've converted it to use array map as you suggested and now when i do:

    alert(out.join("|"));

I get:

    comp_name,c 78 v|addr1,|addr2,|addr3,|addr4,|zip,|vat_exempt1,true|vat_exempt0,false|ddcalled,selcustomers|ddcalled,selcustomers|tbl,customers|popup,1

Which shows that it worked, but when I use "out.indexOf('comp_name')" it returns '-1' instead of '0'?

Comment: As far as I know, `indexOf` doesn't work on multidimensional arrays.

Comment: Thankyou @Cerbrus. That's a shame! By the way, sorry I accidentally accepted your answer when I intended to accept the one below instead! I updated that, because I used his suggested array.map() solution, but I upvoted your reply also for because of your assistance.